# Common data in two cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two cells and I need to get the combined data.
Eg: **Cell A1** has data as AS,CC,DP,SS (count 4) and **Cell B1** has CC,SS,EI,IT (count 4); total 8 and I want my output as AS,CC,DP,SS,EI and IT (count 6 with two overlapping terms appearing once)...how to get this in excel? (no vba)

Comment: what about "=A1&B1", then use find() to check the existence of each pair from one to the other.

Comment: Excel has a `=UNIQUE()` function for removing duplicates, but I have no clue on how to use it for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a combination of functions. First, you can use the `CONCATENATE` function to join the two cell values together. Then, you can use the `SUBSTITUTE` function to replace any duplicate values with a blank string. Then, you can use the `TRIM` function to remove any additional spaces. Finally, you can use the `FILTER` function to filter out any blank values.

```
=FILTER(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(A1,B1),","," ")),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(A1,B1),","," "))<>"")
```

This formula should give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TEXTPLIT` and `TEXTJOIN`:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",,SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,A1:B1),,","))))`